# Cannot import modules in javascript

Tags: javascript, module

I have a script with imports.

I am getting an error on the very first one.

It's not a 404 but a

```
plyr.js:8 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

The modules are on the correct path.

Heres the code that crashes:

```
// ==========================================================================
// Plyr
// plyr.js v3.4.3
// https://github.com/sampotts/plyr
// License: The MIT License (MIT)
// ==========================================================================

import captions from './captions';
........
```

Pretty much a newbie on modules so I'm not sure where to make adjustments.

Comment: Scripts don't use `import` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using the scripts built on `dist` not the ones on `src`. The project uses `gulp` to build the files needed for the browser. You can build them yourself, if you find yourself on a branch without an updated `dist` folder:

```
npm run build
```

You need to download its dev dependencies though.

Answer (score 0):

i think the right path is

```
    import captions from '.src/js/captions';
```